# Переименовать причину закрытия "Дубликат" в "Повтор"

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, причины-закрытия, дубликаты

Всё-таки duplicate это про "двойные" вещи, а повторов на вопрос может быть более чем один.

**Дополнение**

На SE-страничниках (sites) допускается закрытие вопроса как Duplicate, вне зависимости от того, какой из вопросов является старше: т.е. старый вопрос могут закрыть как !дубликат нового, но смысловая нагрузка у слова !дубликат — !копия существующего, а как может быть вопрос, заданный в 2015 году, быть !копией вопроса из 2019-го, например? Это вводит в заблуждение. Слово же Повтор — нет. Вопрос один и неважно когда он будет задан. Каждый последующий или предыдущий повторят один другого. Поэтому предлагаю избавиться от этого двоякого толкования заменой "Дубликат" на "Повтор".

Ссылки по предмету обсуждения:

- [Opinions on closing an older question as a duplicate of a newer question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55251)
- Ключевое пояснение к вопросу выше: [Opinions on closing an older question as a duplicate of a newer question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55251/opinions-on-closing-an-older-question-as-a-duplicate-of-a-newer-question#comment953257_55252)

Comment: Жаль, что вы это написали не пять лет назад, когда сайт переводили на русский. Так-то вариант неплохой, может мы бы его выбрали. Но теперь перевод "дубликат" уже прижился, менять поздно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin выселим)

Comment: Выселим чтобы что? От этого людям станет неудобно на первые пару лет, потому что поменяется привычный им интерфейс и язык. И даже потом *всегда* будет неудобно тем, кто пользуется другими сайтами сети, где используется слово "duplicate". Должна быть очень серьёзная причина, чтобы сделать людям настолько неудобно. У вас есть такая причина?

Comment: В нашем местном сленге уже есть производные этого слова вроде «задубликатить», «отдубликатить» и «раздубликатить». Их тоже придётся менять. Текст в интерфейсе поменять технически несложно, а как вы будете менять живой разговорный язык?

Comment: Довод про "прижился" просто слабый, есть куча слов, которые прижились, а потом вымерли.

Comment: Про производные первый раз слышу.

Comment: @edem так может стоит почаще участвовать в жизни сообщества тогда, чтобы быть в курсе, перед тем, как такое предлагать? )

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica предпочитаю русский язык, а не s(ecret)lang(uage).

Comment: @edem если для вас слово "дубликат" не русское, то у меня для вас плохие новости.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica обсуждение идёт о "местном сленге". ПС. По поводу иностранных слов и заимствований в своё время я всё сказал. Не вижу смысла повторяться в доводах.

Comment: `а как может быть вопрос, заданный в 2015 году, быть !копией вопроса из 2019-го, например?` - как может вопрос, заданный в 2015 году, быть **повтором** вопроса из 2019-го?

Comment: @insolor а я и не говорил, что Повтор рассматривать как !копию другого вопроса. Это лишь указание на схожесть задачи возникшей.

Answer (score 10):

Если не рассматривать старые варианты определения из словарей, а руководствоваться именно применением в обиходе, то я бы следовал источникам поновее, вроде [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82):

> копия, **второй** или **следующий экземпляр**

Предлагаю не трогать текущий перевод.

Тем более, что в оригинале тоже **duplicate**, а не **repetition**.

Comment: LOL, по вашему Википедия - более авторитетный источник, чем словари? О каком "старом" словаре речь?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Ожегов и другие. Нет, я больше про то, что нужно ориентироваться на использование. Дубликат уже используется много лет. Причин менять только потому, что кому-то не нравятся заимствованные слова, не вижу.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight но автор (или вы, если за смену перевода) может добавить ответ с пояснением, почему нужно поменять. Сообщество решит голосованием. Раньше вроде всегда так переводы выбирали.

Comment: Да мне не особо хочется что-то менять. Просто ссылка на Википедию имеет вес еще ниже, чем словари. Не нравятся старые словари - найдите новый.